# Suppress rake in directory message

Tags: ruby, rake

When I run `rake`, it always starts with a message like this:

```
> rake
(in /Users/peter/srcdir)
... standard output here ...
```

I'd like to remove the `(in /Users/peter/srcdir)` portion. You can do it with `rake -s`, but then you don't get the output you want.

Is there any way to disable this current directory announcement but not the rest? Ideal would be some configuration file like `~/.rakerc`, or an option in the `Rakefile` itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't look like it -- [Line 475 of `application.rb`](http://github.com/jimweirich/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/application.rb):

```
puts "(in #{Dir.pwd})" unless options.silent
```

You could try requesting it on the [mailing list](http://rubyforge.org/mail/?group_id=50).

Comment: I want this too, to suppress the error message from Rake which is useless for users.

Comment: I just found that we can use `--suppress-backtrace PATTERN` option to filter out the error message.